# Turn off auto-translate for Firefox

Tags: firefox

How can I turn off auto-translate by Google
I mean this [image]

I have clicked many times on "don't translate for this site" or "don't translate for English"

This doesn't help. The line appears again every time I restart Firefox.

Comment: See if this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/877985/how-to-uninstall-google-translate-toolbar-in-firefox) can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Google Translate toolbar in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/877985/how-to-uninstall-google-translate-toolbar-in-firefox)

Comment: @DavidPostill Why migrate to Web Applications SE instead of closing as a duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/877985/ ? There are two previous comments pointing to that post

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/877985/how-to-uninstall-google-translate-toolbar-in-firefox is old. And, as far as I understand, the method is described for Explorer, not Firefox